# subtracting the greater column from smaller columns in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subtraction

I have the input below and I would like to subtract the two columns, but I want to subtract always the lowest value from the highest value.
Because I don't want negative values as a result and sometimes the highest value is in the first column (PaternalOrgin) and other times in the second column (MaternalOrigin).

Input:

```
df <- PaternalOrigin MaternalOrigin
16             20
3              6
11              0
1              3
1              4
3             11
```

and the dput output is this:

```
df <- structure(list(PaternalOrigin = c(16, 3, 11, 1, 1, 3), MaternalOrigin = c(20, 6, 0, 3, 4, 11)), colnames = c("PaternalOrigin", "MaternalOrigin"), row.names= c(NA, -6L), class="data.frame")
```

Thus, my expected output would look like:

```
df2 <- PaternalOrigin MaternalOrigin Results
16             20       4
3              6       3
11              0      11
1              3       2
1              4       3
3             11       8
```

Please, can someone advise me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can wrap with `abs`

```
transform(df, Results = abs(PaternalOrigin - MaternalOrigin))
#     PaternalOrigin MaternalOrigin Results
#1             16             20       4
#2              3              6       3
#3             11              0      11
#4              1              3       2
#5              1              4       3
#6              3             11       8
```

---

Or we can assign it to 'Results'

```
df$Results <- with(df, abs(PaternalOrigin - MaternalOrigin))
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Results := abs(PaternalOrigin - MaternalOrigin)]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    mutate(Results = abs(PaternalOrigin - MaternalOrigin))
```